# How to crop a song and mantain the same values in the sample vector?

Tags: discrete-signals, audio, array-signal-processing

Does anyone know how can I crop an audio signal and maintain the same values in the sample vector?

I am working on a audio signal processing project for song recognition in Python and I wanted to crop a song in Audacity. To my surprise, the audio samples (for both the left and right channel) in the cropped version were "corrupted", meaning that they were different from the corresponding samples from the original song.

Comment: maybe audacity performed some audio format conversions on the way?

Comment: Hi @Adrian, and welcome to DSP.SE. What format do you use? If it is a compressed format, Audacity had to decode the file for loading it and encode it again for saving. The compression algorithm may have produced different sample values, possibly depending on the surrounding samples of your cropped region.

Comment: Thank you @applesoup for the warm welcome! I use .wav files in order no to lose too much information from the signal. I am quite at the beginning in this field, so I don't know so much about the various formats. Would you recommend choosing another format?

Comment: @MarcusMüller perhaps this is the case. I also tried cropping a song with an online tool and also changed the sample vector. I don't know whether it's because of the wav format that I use or the tool for cropping.

Comment: @Adrian .wav is just a container. It can contain different kinds of compressed and uncompressed data.

Comment: @Adrian have you checked whether maybe the values are just multiplied with a constant?

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry for the late reply. Yes, I have checked, but that does not seem to be the case. Here are the first values from the left channel for the same song, one cropped to be 6 seconds long, the other, 10 seconds long:


10SecondsOfAPianoSong: [-2 -3  4 -3  0  4 -7  5 -1 -1  3 -3  0  2 -2  3 -3  0 ..
6SecondsOfTheSameSng: [ 0 -5  5 -4  1  3 -5  3 -1 -1  4 -4  2  0 -2  5 -5  2 ..

Comment: since I really can't reproduce this locally, maybe upload the original and the cropped versions somewhere.

Comment: Here are the two audio files:
https://we.tl/t-onhdEuGYZV

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have uploaded the audio files above

Comment: Since you are working in Python anyways, why don't you crop your samples in Python directly? Then you have control over what happens to the samples...